# Listview ItemCommand not firing because of jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, css

I have a **listview** of categories with **checkboxes** (categories filter). But I have made a **custom checkBoxes** (linkButton with css is my checkBox).

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="checkBox" runat="server">

.checkbox {background: url('/style/images/checkbox.png') no-repeat top left;width:9px;height:9px;text-decoration:none;
.checked {background: url('/style/images/selected_checkbox.png') no-repeat top left;}
```

And in **jQuery** in document ready on linkButton(my custom checkbox click) I **change css**(add checked class)

```
$(".filter-select .checkbox").click(function () {
            if ($(this).hasClass('checked'))
                $(this).removeClass('checked');
            else $(this).addClass('checked');

            return false;
        });
```

Everything works just fine, but when I want to **handle checked chekcboxes on listview itemCommand**, the itemCommand does not fire... If I remove jquery call, everything is o.k, so I think jquery blocks or prevents itemCommand to fire on linkButton click.

But I would need to have this itemCommand call so what should I do? Should I remove/change the way I have this checkBox with jQuery. Or did I miss something... I have also try with 
**OnClientClick="this.disabled='true';"** that I have seen is some other post, but there were no results..

Comment: I think you should call the dopostback() manually in this case.. as you have intercepted the normally functions of the asp.net generated code.. or remove the `return false`

Comment: If I remove return false, the itemCommand is fired but the css of linkButton control is not changed... Maybe I should realy consider to change this jQuery CSS think with something else - maybe I should change this css in itemCommand and not in jQuery

Comment: hmm... actually if you are not using ajax then, when the itemCommand is fired and then when it returns it reRenders your whole page. In which case there is no chance for the above style to be applied.

Comment: YOu should write your code in $(document).ready() and apply style to the desired checkboxs. then it can solve your problem. the above solution will work if you use ajax to post to the server. In full page postback() this is not going to work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I have change my approch and remove the jQuery thinkg... I have put everything in ItemCommand method, so I get the control in itemCommand like

```
LinkButton selected = e.Item.FindControl("id") as LinkButton;
```

Then I check the classes like:

```
selected.CssClass = (selected.CssClass != "checkbox checked") ? "checkbox checked" : "checkbox";
```

And than I check for all the checked linkButtons(custom checkBoxes)

So no jQuery interupt needed. Thanks for help

Comment: I hope my solution is o.k ... I will also use updatePanel to prevent full postback on itemCommand fire and that's it... Correct me if I am wrong. But thing's working now, I can change the css and get the ids by dataKeyNames so I found my solution.

Comment: This is nice too.. are  you using Updatepanel there?

Comment: Yes I will for preventing the full postback on checkbox state change... Thanks for help Spirals Whirls..